# Oracle Forms Standalone Launcher | Close Application Window

Tags: oracleforms

We're moving our Oracle Forms application from IE to FSAL. In IE closing the browser was enough to **close the application**. Using FSAL pressing 'close' on the application window results in closing the current form, **not in closing the application**.

Question: does anyone have a suggestion what to do to **mimic the IE behaviour** (close the application instead of a single form) in FSAL. Thanks for your help!

Already tried: close all open forms if system.event_window = 'FORMS_MDI_WINDOW' unfortunately this requires code change in 300+ forms.

Answer (score 0):

Closing a running Forms application by closing the browser window was never a good idea.  This did what you described with IE because IE is just a container running the Java Plugin, which was running Forms in it.  The browser had no idea what Forms was doing and no Forms had no idea what the browser was doing.  So when the big X at the upper right was clicked, it was about the same as pulling the plug out of the wall of your computer.

So in the case where you have changed the hosting platform (move from IE to FSAL), if you (your org) has included a trigger in the application that is overriding the default closure process then that trigger will need to be updated.  There is, unfortunately no magic switch (e.g. `FORMS_IGNORE_WHAT_I_PREVIOUSLY_ASKED_YOU_TO_DO=TRUE`) option. If you want to change the behavior, you need to change the code.

In a case where there is more than one module, you can use JDAPI (or CAPI) to programmatically make changes to many modules at one time.  However, in order to do this you need someone who knows Java and/or C and knows Forms to write the code to make the change.  Details about using the Forms JDAPI can be found in the Builder Help and in a variety of Support notes.

There are also some third party tools that may be able to help make such a change.  One example might be to try FormsAPI Master.  Alternatively, there are some Oracle Partners that have developed tooling to help you do the change.  Of course, that service will not be free of charge.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Michael. Since we're still using Oracle Designer to generate our Forms we're able to modify the olb & regenerate the forms. I will mark the question as solved. Best regards!